# How to make div height whole page even when I scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have side `div` with side menu in it and I want to make `div` height whole page, even if I
scroll down.

I tried height 100vh gives height of screen page;
height 100% I get height until I have menu no more.

```
.menu {
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
    background: #151515;
    height:100vh;
}
```

Next to side menu is main content that exceed height of menu, so i want even if i scroll down that main content background of that menu still goes to the end.

Comment: Please consider posting your markup as well, also providing an online example on jsfiddle would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want a menu that stays on your screen even if you scroll down?

Try this:

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #151515;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try absolute positioning:

```
.menu {
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 350px;
    background: #151515;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with scrolling, needs to be `fixed`

Comment: It doesn't work at all